# alignment for a specific table

Tags: html, css

please be nice :D
i am trying to align a specific table in html, tried to use "id" and then call it from a css file and style it, but with no success.
my goal is to build a protfolio web-page, i will share pics in a few paragraphs.
i need to align a specific table for it to be just under the rest of the page elements.
when ever i start a new table it goes to the left side, and it is ugly..
how can i do it ?
the code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Asaf Danan's Resume Site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css_index.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <table cellspacing="100">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img
            src="./image/rope access.jpg"
            alt="pic of me at work"
            width="200"
            height="200"
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <h1>Asaf Danan</h1>
          <p>
            <i> rope access surfer at </i>
            <a href="https://dream-t.co.il"> Dream-Team</a>
          </p>
          <hr>
          <p>
           rope accesser at Dream-Team, implies all kinds of construction tasks and up to 50 meters high.
           Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur eligendi cum repellat. adipisicing elit. Voluptates aut exercitationem reprehenderit odio provident ullam
           est ducimus officia et debitis adipisci voluptatem atque, fugit voluptatcusamus iure perspiciatis quae eligendi cum repellat.
           blah blah blah, blah blah blah, blah blah blah, and another Blah blah blah
          <br>
          hello hello hello my name is asaf my name is my name is my name is
          </br>
          hahahahahahahahaha
          <hr>
          <h3 id="idname">Education</h3>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <i><b>Height course</b></i>
            </li>
            <li>
              <i><b>Sealing course</b></i>
            </li>
            <li>
              <i><b>Building Surfing Course</b></i>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <hr>
          </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table cellspacing="60">
    

      <tr>
        <th>
          exfoliate
        </th>
      </tr>
    </table>
   
      </tr>
      <tr>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>`
```

can someone help me out?
thanks :D

pic:enter code here
[the web page i am working on, with the issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nm2zq.png)

Comment: If you want to align the new table with the text above, you'll have to make the same space as for the image above. BUT I would highly suggest to look at css solutions like Flexbox or Grid, that you can use to create the layout in a more easy way instead of using tables.
Flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
Grid: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

https://www.thoughtco.com/dont-use-tables-for-layout-3468941

Comment: the lecturer said to not use another method even if it is easier, he wants to teach us that in the next few classes.
right now he wants us to use tables.
how can i accomplish what i am looking for?
u see the beggining of the page? it's alligned in a specific way, center ish and left ish.. when i started a new table, it alligned to the hardcore left, how can i change it?
i centered it using css class:


  <table cellspacing="100" class="center" >


and css:


.center {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }